# Spark aggregateByKey: using the key

Tags: apache-spark

I want to create a set of bloom filters from my RDD. The way I do it looks like the following:

```
rdd.aggregateByKey(create(size))(add, combine).collect()
```

Where `rdd` is something like `RDD[(Int, Long)]`

The problem is that the values are not distributed uniformly within each group. That is, "one `size` fits all" doesn't work here and I want to initialize the bloom filters differently for each key, depending on how many elements are there.

So I want something like

```
rdd.aggregateByKey(key => create(count(key))(add, combine).collect()
```

Where `count` is a map with counts.

This is something I can do with `groupByKey`, but I wonder, is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple trick you can use. Convert `RDD` from `(key, value)` to `(key, (key, value))`:

```
val kkvRdd = rdd.map { case (key, value) => (key, (key, value)) }
```

and apply `combineByKey`:

```
def createCombiner(v: (Int, Long)) = create(count(_._1))  // And insert _._2

kkvRdd.combineByKey(createCombiner, add,  combine)
```

where `add` and `combine` are adjusted to accept new type.